# Shiro Integration with Guice

Tags: java, guice, shiro

I am trying to integrate Guice with Shiro. I'm pulling in the latest Shiro JARs with:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
  <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-guice</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
  <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am unable to compile the code provided in the [Shiro documentation](http://shiro.apache.org/guice.html).

```java
class MyShiroModule extends ShiroModule {
  protected void configureShiro() {
    try {
      // compile time error is shown with error message:
      // "Method toConstructor is undefined in type LinkedBindingBuilder". 
      bindRealm().toConstructor(IniRealm.class.getConstructor(Ini.class));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      addError(e);
    }
  }
  @Provides
  Ini loadShiroIni() {
    return Ini.fromResourcePath("classpath:shiro.ini");
  }
}
```

It seems like there is some JAR versioning problem.

**First Question**

Whatis the appropriate Maven configuration to compile this code?

**Second Question**

I always face this type of version problem and search the net for the correct version. Or use one version over another run of the program and confirm that the program runs. Is there a way to overcome this type of version problem so that one version of a JAR is compatible with every version?

Comment: What does the rest of your POM look like? Are you sure you have the correct version of Guice on your classpath? The `LinkedBindingBuilder` is in the Guice jar, not the Shiro jar.

Answer (score 0):

Some classes of Shiro packages has the same name of native java classes, make sure that you are importing the correct classes.